# Google Cloud Scheduler cannot find Python Script Cloud Run jobname

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

When I run the script as a cloud function it can find the job name but when I run it in cloud run jobs it can't find the job name.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

httpRequest: {1}
insertId: "8vr1cwfi77fef"
jsonPayload: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished"
jobName: "projects/api-data-pod/locations/us-central1/jobs/mouse-recording"
status: "NOT_FOUND"
targetType: "HTTP"
url: "https://us-central1-run.googleapis.com/apis/run.googleapis.com/v1/namespaces/api-data-pod/jobs/mouseflowrecording:run"
}
logName: "projects/api-data-pod/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions"
receiveTimestamp: "2022-08-02T11:54:04.664184360Z"
resource: {
labels: {3}
type: "cloud_scheduler_job"
}
severity: "ERROR"
timestamp: "2022-08-02T11:54:04.664184360Z"
}

````
import requests

import json

import pandas as pd

import pandas_gbq

from google.cloud import bigquery

from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

#import schedule

#import time

def rec(request):
    r = requests.get("https://api-eu.mouseflow.com/websites/e768ed54-c09b-48dc-bf49-beda12697013/recordings",

    auth=HTTPBasicAuth("*************", "********************"))

    if r.status_code == 200:
        
        parsed = json.loads(r.text)

        print(json.dumps(parsed['recordings'], indent=4, sort_keys=True))

        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(parsed['recordings'])

        #print(df.dtypes) 
      
       
        #df.to_csv('mousedata3.csv')#
        try:
            temp_csv_string = df.to_csv(sep=";", index=False)
            temp_csv_string_IO = StringIO(temp_csv_string)
    # create new dataframe from string variable
            new_df = pd.read_csv(temp_csv_string_IO, sep=";")
    # this new df can be uploaded to BQ with no issues
            new_df.to_gbq('Mouseflow.Mouseflow_Recording', if_exists='replace', project_id='api-data-pod')
            return f'Successful'
        except Exception as err:
            return f'Upload to BigQuery failed: {err}'
    else:
        return f'API request error occurred: Status code {r.status_code}'
rec(requests.request)```
Hi here is the python code that is causing the problem.

It works with cloud functions perfectly but it can't find the jobname of cloud run jobs for some reason.

The only difference with the cloud function code is that I don;t have an end to function as it is not needed. So this is not at the end of my code rec(requests.request).

I hope this is explains things a bit better.
````

Comment: We cannot know "what you're doing wrong" if you don't show what you're doing. Please edit your question and show your code.

Comment: Hi @FerreginaPelona I hope this explains things a bit better as I have the python code here.